# Inline function with template in header file causes identifier not found error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries, inline

I have an inline function definition in a header file in c++ as follows.

```
draw.h
namespace nameSp
{
    template<typename T>
    inline void functionName( const Eigen::Matrix<T,3,3>& Kinv, int w, int h, const Eigen::Matrix<T,4,4>& T_wf, T scale )
    {
    }
}
```

and I am trying to link this file as a library in another program as follows.

```
#include <nameSp/draw.h> 

Eigen::Matrix3f Kinv = K.inverse();
nameSp::functionName(Kinv,
                     Resolution::getInstance().width(),
                     Resolution::getInstance().height(),
                     pose,
                     0.1f);
```

But the other program is not able to find the function and throws the error 'functionName:identifier not found'.

There is no problem linking other inline functions without template definition in the same header files . I am fairly new into the concept of template. Kindly help.

Comment: How are you trying to "link this file"? Are you not simply including it like a normal header file?

Comment: In "the other program", all you have to do should be to include this header file. Did you do that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I am creating a .lib file of the first program and linking it to the other program using visual studio.

Comment: @DonghuiZhang : I am including the header file as well

Comment: I think it's time you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. In the "other program", how are you using this function? What arguments are you passing it? What are the types of those arguments?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : i have edited the main thread.

Comment: When you call functionName, try give it a template parameter.

Comment: 'functionName:identifier not found' doesn't look like a linker error, but a compiler one. I suspect you simply mis-typed the function name in one of the two places, so the two don't match.

Comment: but the template parameter should be known when the values are passed?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : I have double checked. The function name is same. Function is not visible as a member of the namespace.

Comment: Then the header you are including is not the one you think you are including, but some stale copy that doesn't in fact have the function definition. Or, there's more to the issue than you are telling us.

Comment: The header is correct since other methods without template definition is visible as the members of the namespace. The problem is with the template defined methods